# On dit « Ça dépend de l’endroit où vous allez », dirait-on « Ça dépend d’où vous allez » ou « Ça dépend où vous allez »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Dit-on plutôt

> « Ça dépend de/d’où vous allez »

Ou  (à dessein de simplification)

> « Ça dépend où vous allez »

Il s’agit d’une tournure qui prend modèle sur « Ça dépend de l’endroit où vous allez » et elle doit véhiculer le même message que la phrase qui sert de modèle.

Edit***

http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/indirectes.html#640

Dépendre de

Dans le fran­çais parlé, après la cons­truc­­tion ça dépend, on construit cou­ram­ment dépendre avec une in­ter­ro­ga­tive in­di­recte :
Ça dépend si on aura le temps ou pas. ■ Ça dépend à quelle heure vous venez. ■ Ça dépend un peu com­ment il réagira. ■ Ça dépend quand le film com­mence. ■ Ça dépend ce qu’il en pense. ■ Ça dépend com­ment tu veux faire.
Cepen­dant, dans le code écrit strict, ces tournures ne sont pas admises. Il faut recourir à des cons­truc­tions plus ou moins « compliquées » :
Cela dépend de la ques­tion de savoir si nous en aurons le temps. / Cela dépend du temps dont nous disposerons. ■ Cela dépend de l’heure à laquelle vous venez. ■ Cela dépend de la ma­niè­re dont il réagira. / Cela dépend de sa réaction. ■ Cela dépend de l’heure à laquelle le film com­mence. ■ Cela dépend de ce qu’il en pense. ■ Cela dépend de la ma­niè­re dont tu veux procéder.

Comment: Je vois que tu n'envisages pas de ne pas élider le « de » (Ça dépend de où....) qui se fait souvent à l'oral, sinon il me semble que le « de » ne se met que devant un nom et que devant où c'est plutôt familier (on le rencontre beaucoup pourtant). Mais à vérifier.

Comment: "Ça dépend **du chemin** que vous prenez pour y aller".

Comment: *Ça dépend d'ousque vous allez*...

Comment: Et *[ousque](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ousque)* a l'air vivace au Québec.

Comment: @jlliagre J’étais certain que ces deux termes (sarcastique et ironique) étaient synonymes; si je me reporte au dictionnaire français «linternaute.com » ils le seraient! Il doit y avoir une nuance que mon petit cerveau peine à déceler.

Comment: C'est le ton, l'intention qui peut différencier les deux. L'ironie cherche à mettre les rieurs de son côté, elle est souvent plaisante. Le sarcasme manifeste de l'hostilité, de la malveillance. Il cherche à blesser.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci pour cette précision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quel statut faut-il donner à la construction qui suit *dépendre de*, quand ce dernier n'est pas suivi d'un substantif mais directement du « mot » introduisant la subordonnée, et dans ce cas peut-on/doit-on conserver sa préposition au verbe ?

Le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9pendre//1) (AC) n'émet même pas l'hypothèse que *dépendre de* ne soit pas suivi par autre chose qu'un GN :

> **Cela/ça dépend de** + subst. *absol*. **cela/ça dépend**. Cela est variable ou incertain; cela est subordonné à l'accomplissement de certaines conditions.
> *Ça dépend des jours. Cela dépend de l'endroit où vous allez* (Soulié).

Dans sa [*Syntaxe du français contemporain – Les propositions subordonnées*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1568h/f83) dont la première édition est parue en 1936, Kristian Sandfeld écrivait :

> Les propositions interrogatives indirectes ne sont, généralement, pas susceptibles d'être régies par des prépositions, exceptées si elles sont introduites par *ce qui* (*ce que*) (...) ailleurs on intercale *de savoir*, *pour savoir* (...) ou bien on se sert d'autres expressions, on peut intercaler *ceci*, on peut choisir le tour par une proposition relative (...).

Quelques lignes plus bas il ajoute :

> On peut enfin omettre la préposition et ajouter directement la proposition interrogative. [...] **Dans la langue familière cette construction est très fréquente avec dépendre**<sup>1</sup>. (...)  *Ça dépend comment tu l'entends*.

Dans le chapitre sur les complétives interrogatives indirectes de *[La grammaire française de l'étudiant finnophone](https://jyx.jyu.fi/handle/123456789/37015)* Jean-Michel Kalmbach suit la même idée:

> En français, l’interrogative indirecte est une complétive en fonction de complément direct du verbe. Elle ne peut être le complément que de verbes transitifs directs (dont le complément est relié au verbe sans préposition) : ne pas savoir qch, se demander qch, ignorer qch etc.
> Pour cette raison, **en français, on ne peut pas utiliser une interrogative indirecte après un verbe à complément prépositionnel**, comme réfléchir à, s’intéresser à, se concentrer sur, **dépendre de**<sup>1</sup> etc.

Et plus loin dans le même chapitre il ajoute un paragraphe spécifique sur la construction avec *ça dépend* :

> Dans le français parlé, après la construction *ça dépend*, on construit couramment *dépendre* avec une interrogative indirecte :
> *Ça dépend si on aura le temps ou pas*. ■ *Ça dépend un peu comment il réagira*. ■ *Ça dépend quand le film com­mence*.  ■ *Ça dépend comment tu veux faire*.

> Cependant, dans le code écrit strict, ces tournures ne sont pas admises. Il faut recourir à des constructions plus ou moins « compliquées » :
> *Cela dépend de la question de savoir si nous en aurons le temps*. / *Cela dépend du temps dont nous disposerons*. ■ *Cela dépend de la manière dont il réagira*. / Cela dépend de sa réaction. ■ *Cela dépend de l’heure à laquelle le film com­mence*. ■ *Cela dépend de la manière dont tu veux procéder*.

Il semble donc que le « code écrit strict » demande la présence d'un groupe nominal après *ça dépend de* mais que dans la langue courante, quand le groupe nominal n'est pas exprimé, on ne mette pas la préposition.
Quelques recherches montrent en effet que ce sont dans des dialogues que l'on trouve la tournure *ça dépend de* suivi directement par l'interrogative indirecte : [*ça dépend où vous allez*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20o%C3%B9%20vous%20allez%22), [*ça dépend combien*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20combien%22&biw=1860&bih=909&tbm=bks&ei=nxHkYc3IKousa5naiNAI&ved=0ahUKEwiNlKzvpLb1AhUL1hoKHRktAooQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%22%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20combien%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQAFgAYLO4AWgBcAB4AIABOogBOpIBATGYAQDAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books), [*ça dépend comment*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20comment%22&biw=1860&bih=909&tbm=bks&ei=xBHkYcf6O8Ksa_e-tbgF&ved=0ahUKEwjH7I-Bpbb1AhVC1hoKHXdfDVcQ4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%22%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20comment%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ7AhY2hBguh9oAHAAeACAAT2IAaUDkgEBOJgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books),  [*ça dépend quel*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20quel%22&biw=1860&bih=909&tbm=bks&ei=8hHkYevrJsOUlwSzirPwCw&ved=0ahUKEwjrrPKWpbb1AhVDyoUKHTPFDL4Q4dUDCAg&uact=5&oq=%22%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20quel%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQvAhY9BBgtBloAHAAeACAATyIAY0CkgEBNZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-books), etc.

Nous n'avons cependant toujours pas envisagé le cas posé dans la question :  peut-on conserver sa préposition à *dépendre* si la complétive suit juste après ? En cherchant sur un petit corpus accessible dans google books, on peut voir que si [*ça dépend où vous allez*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20o%C3%B9%20vous%20allez%22) est fréquent [*ça dépend d'où vous allez*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20d%27o%C3%B9%20vous%20allez%22) est quasiment inexistant. Pour *[ça dépend comment](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20comment%22)* vs [*ça dépend de comment*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20de%20comment%22) et [*ça dépend combien*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20combien%22) vs [*ça dépend de combien*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20de%20combien%22) dans chaque cas la partie semble à peu près égale. On pourrait faire d'autres recherches dont les résultats varient probablement en fonction du mot interrogatif utilisé et de ses possibilités de polysémie.

Alors les deux constructions sont-elles strictement équivalentes ?
Sur le [forum de wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%C3%87a-d%C3%A9pend-de-combien-de-temps.1289481/) un participant cite Grevisse :

> Pour Grevisse (§1162, b, 6°), on peut garder la préposition « [d]ans une langue moins soignée, reflet de l'oral familier, devant d'autres interrogatifs [que *ce qui*, *ce que*] ».

Pour Grevisse donc garder la préposition est moins soigné que de ne pas la garder. Je n'ai rien trouvé sur le pourquoi, mais il me semble raisonnable de penser que c'est parce que dans la langue soutenue « l’interrogative indirecte est une complétive en fonction de complément direct du verbe ».

Dans la langue soignée écrite par contre, à l'instar de Bruno Dewaele, certains « répugne[nt] (le mot est faible) à faire suivre la préposition d'un mot interrogatif » (voir son billet d'humeur « [Grammaire nase](http://alafortunedumot.blogs.lavoixdunord.fr/archive/2015/07/14/grammaire-nase-14135.html) » dans *la Voix du Nord* du 14/04/2015).

Pour répondre à la question posée je dirai que nous sommes face à trois options selon le registre et le niveau niveau de langue souhaité :
■ *Ça dépend de l'endroit où vous allez* pour un langage écrit soutenu.
■ *Ça dépend où vous allez pour un langage parlé* courant.
■ *Ça dépend d'où vous allez* pour un langage parlé familier.

Le sujet est à la fois complexe et compliqué et, comme le fait remarquer l'auteur de l'excellent site « Parler français – Richesse et difficultés de la langue française » qui traite de *ça dépend de* dans son article [« Un tour pendable »](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/un-tour-pendable-a130605366), dont je recommande la lecture en entier :

> D'aucuns se demanderont tout de même s'il ne conviendrait pas plutôt de rétablir la préposition *de* dans tous ces cas, aux dépens de la tradition.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> C'est moi qui souligne.</sup>

---

Answer (score -1):

Dépendre **de** ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9pendre/1), A1a), A1b), A2a), A2b))

Si l'on s'en rapporte à la pratique habituelle, il faut toujours reprendre la préposition qui suit naturellement un verbe.

Reposer **sur** ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/reposer), IB4)
Aboutir **à**  ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aboutir), IA1)
Arriver **à** ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/arriver), IC1)

« Dépendre de où », « dépend de où », « dépendait de où », ne strouvent pas du tout : [ngram 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=d%C3%A9pend+de+o%C3%B9%2Cd%C3%A9pendre+de+o%C3%B9%2Cd%C3%A9pendait+de+o%C3%B9&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=).

[image]

[ngram 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=d%C3%A9pend+d%27o%C3%B9&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9pend%20d%27%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9pend%20d%27%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0)

Il n'y a aucune raison grammaticale qui permette une construction où la préposition ferait défaut ; je ne pense pas que l'on parle dans quelque ouvrage que ce soit d'exceptions à cette règle, sauf dans des cas rares de répétition due à un ou plusieurs termes coordonnés ([WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/r%C3%A9p%C3%A9tition-de-la-pr%C3%A9position-devant-des-termes-coordonn%C3%A9s.1391117/)) ou bien dans des cas beaucoup plus fréquents  où le mot, encore une fois, est un pronom ([internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/ou-1/)), ou un adverbe (ça dépend qui, dépend quoi, dépend comment,  …)

On examine ci-dessous  divers  cas, mais partiellement.

**Où**

[image]

**Comment**        On voit que la préposition est beaucoup plus souvent omise (une comparaison de la [page « dépend comment »](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22d%C3%A9pend%20comment%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) avec la [page « dépend de comment »](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22d%C3%A9pend%20de%20comment%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) montre qu'il n'y a pas de différence dans le sens).

[image]

[ngram 3](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A7a+d%C3%A9pend+d%27o%C3%B9%2C%C3%A7a+d%C3%A9pend+o%C3%B9&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20d%27%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20d%27%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20o%C3%B9%3B%2Cc0)

**Qui**             En ce qui concerne « qui », l'usage de la préposition est dominant.

[image: ![enter image description here]

[ngram 4](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A7a+d%C3%A9pend+de+qui%2C%C3%A7a+d%C3%A9pend+qui%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20de%20qui%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20qui%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20de%20qui%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20qui%3B%2Cc0)

**Quoi**              Le modèle pour ce pronom suit celui de « qui » sauf que la préférence est plus prononcée.

[image]

[ngram 5](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A7a+d%C3%A9pend+de+quoi%2C+%C3%A7a+d%C3%A9pend+quoi&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20de%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A7a%20d%C3%A9pend%20quoi%3B%2Cc0)

**Quel/quelle**              La tendance s'accentue pour « quel/quelle ».

[image]

[image]

Le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9pendre/1) est parfaitement ignorant de cet usage sans « de ». On peut voir [ici (WordReference)](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%C3%87a-d%C3%A9pend-de-comment.2181448/) que les opinions pourraient être partagées et qu'en Suisse Romande on pourrait même considérer que l'usage de la préposition est incorrect.

Mon opinion personnelle, malgré la forte prédominance de l'usage de la préposition dans les cas de « où » et « comment », est que de la préserver est préférable et dénote d'un langage plus pur, cela du fait que la pratique exceptionnelle de ne pas se conformer au principe d'utilisation de la préposition laisse le sens intact ; de plus la fonctionnalité grammaticale se trouve renforcée, il n'y a aucune exception dont les raisons inexistantes puissent troubler l'esprit de quiconque en quête de justification. Évidemment, puisqu'il est plus ou moins admis que la majorité numérique fait l'usage, on doit pouvoir dire « dépend où vous allez », c'est une question de choix personnel.

Ainsi lorsque la dépendance est vis à vis de la provenance il faudrait dire « ça dépend de d'où vous venez », mais cette construction n'est jamais utilisé ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=d%C3%A9pend+de+d%27o%C3%B9&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=)), et « ça dépend d'où vous venez, d'où vous partez, d'où vous tirez, etc. » sera tout ce que l'on trouvera, l'esprit humain ne pouvant pas reconnaitre la logique de cette construction. Par exemple « ça dépend d'où vous partez en vacances » ne signifie pas « ça dépend de d'où vous partez en vacances ».